# Google Apps Script onOpen() trigger sheet.activate() - spreadsheet is not updated for 5-7 seconds

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple onOpen() trigger defined in a Google Spreadsheet bound script
that sets the active tab to tabName

```
function onOpen(e)
{
    ss = e.source
    ss.getSheetByName(tabName).activate()
}
```

This works fine but takes 5 to 7 seconds to be reflected in the spreadsheet.
In that time, a user may already start editing on the default/incorrect sheet.
Suggestions for speeding up or locking until the spreadsheet catches up to the script?

There are suggestion that you just make the tab you want to be active the first tab. But what if the tabs indicate chronology (for instance, months or quarters)? You'd like to retain the order, so, for instance, if you want March to be the active sheet, you don't want March to come before January in the spreadsheet chronology. You just want to activate it.

The problem is exacerbated by the fact that, unlike Excel, Google Sheets does not retain the last active sheet as the default--it always defaults to the first sheet.

This is my first question in stackoverflow. I don't think this is an outrageously stupid question. I thought the point of stackoverflow was to ask questions that hadn't been asked and answered before. Otherwise I would have already found an answer. I'm also wondering why it takes 5-7 seconds merely to activate a sheet. When I manually select a tab, it is nearly instantaneous. There seems to be a high time overhead for scripting this action. I've never been satisfied with answers like 'That's the way it is--live with it!'

Comment: Which tabName depends on?

Comment: I can't remember ever having this question before.  And I'm guessing that it's because the simple answer is to move the sheet you want the spreadsheet to open on to the left most position which is position zero.  And that's the sheet it will open to.  And if you want it to snap another position immediately upon opening then the answer is use excel not google sheets because it's not going to happen.  It takes about as long as it takes for our custom menus to popup.  Personally, I don't mind the display.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to speed up is to place the tabName in the first position. For instance, if the tabName is the last modified tab, you can do

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  if(sh.getIndex()>1){ss.moveActiveSheet(0)}
}
```